# unable to install [R] package KernSmooth on Windows- error: package ‘KernSmooth’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

OS: Windows 7
RStudio installed
R ver. 3.5.1

attempted to install KernSmotth package with:
install.packages("KernSmooth")

output:
*Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘KernSmooth’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)*

I reset repository option with:
*options(repos = getOption("repos")["CRAN"])*
still the same error.

KernSmooth is a CRAN package and am able to access:
*http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES*

which verifies this assumption.
I am able to access *https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/* from my browser too
and this does not seem to be a proxy issue.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely your browser uses a proxy to access these pages. You have to configure this proxy for R as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was environmental
when I changed *CRAn mirror* via chooseCRANmirror()
and set it to an accessible for my IP site it worked:

*> install.packages("KernSmooth")
trying URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/KernSmooth_2.23-15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 113884 bytes (111 KB)
downloaded 111 KB
package ‘KernSmooth’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcDQuVX\downloaded_packages

> local({pkg <- select.list(sort(.packages(all.available = TRUE)),graphics=TRUE)
>   + if(nchar(pkg)) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)})
>   KernSmooth 2.23 loaded
>   Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009*

thanks